# Binding ItemsSource dependency property in custom control

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, custom-controls

I have a custom control that has a dependency property that should fill a datagrid's ItemsSource property in the control. For some reason the collection never gets filled and the ItemsSource always ends up empty.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsSourceProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", GetType(ObservableObjectCollection), GetType(HomePageControl), New PropertyMetadata(New ObservableObjectCollection, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf ItemsSourceCallback)))

Public Property ItemsSource As ObservableObjectCollection
        Get
            Return DirectCast(GetValue(HomePageControl.ItemsSourceProperty), ObservableObjectCollection)
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableObjectCollection)
            SetValue(HomePageControl.ItemsSourceProperty, value)
        End Set
End Property
```

Xaml:

```
        <Controls:HomePageControl x:Name="myControl"
                                  Margin="0,25,0,0" 
                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                  HeaderText="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=CurrentUser, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                                  HeaderCount="30"
                                  HeaderLinkText="This is optional."
                                  HeaderLinkURI="/Projects"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainViewModel}, Path=TaskList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Default}"
                                  GridViewStyle="{StaticResource RadGridViewStyleNoFlag}"
                                  />
```

I have five other DPs that work just fine, 3 strings and one style (to set up the columns of the datagrid) and a URI. I can either set them directly, as in "This is optional", or by binding them like the HeaderText, but the ItemsSource property never seems to get bound... a gridview outside of the control that uses the same binding as used in the ItemsSource binding inside the control gets filled... so the binding does return a filled collection, but it is not making it to the datagrid inside the custom control.

If I change ObservableObjectCollection to the object type that I'm using in the collection that I bind, then it works fine. The reason I want to use ObservableObjectCollection is because I want to be able to bind any object to the datagrid, just like a datagrid can... it doesn't care what type you bind to it - how can I get my user control to not care?

Comment: Does `PropertyChanged` event fires?

Comment: @anatoliiG Nothing fires when it is set to ObservableObjectCollection, ItemsSourceCallback fires when I set it to a typed observable collection.